# Improving speed of macro loop to carry out data conversions on c. 76,000 rows of data

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I have experimented with two different ways of configuring a spreadsheet tool I have which is for converting data provided by a client to our own data codes.

The data sets can get particularly large (this one is 76,335 rows), so macro performance is important.

The first method I tried is to record a series of index/match formulas into VBA, and have the code insert these into Columns M to Y and drag down to wherever the last row in the original data set is (which lives in Cols A to J).  Only one of these formulas is an array formula, and I have tried the code without the array formula with little overall benefit. This method (let’s call it method A) took 14 minutes 8 seconds (Windows PC with i7-2600 CPU and 8 GB of RAM).

Thinking it would improve performance if I had VBA do the calculations which the excel formulas were doing, I ran the following loop (method B).

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To lastRow

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONVERSION")

        If Range("M" & i) = "BIN" Then
            Range("N" & i) = "Duplicate"
        Else
            Range("N" & i) = Range("B" & i) & "-" & Range("D" & i) & "-" & Range("M" & i)
        End If

        If Range("B" & i) = "Duplicate" Then
            Range("O" & i) = "D"
            Else
            Range("O" & i) = "N"
        End If

        If Range("E2") = "Groundwater" Then
            Range("P" & i) = "WG"
            ElseIf Range("E2") = "Leachate" Then
            Range("P" & i) = "LE"
            ElseIf Range("E2") = "Surface water" Then
            Range("P" & i) = "WS"
            Else
            Range("P" & i) = "Other"
        End If

        'Plus another six If statements similar to the above to populate Cols P to Y... Not included here to keep this code on StackOverflow easier to read

    End With

Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This, surprisingly took 27 minutes 27 seconds. This is despite having `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Why is it that the VBA calculations method is slower? Is it something to do with my looping being inefficient? Could it be because the VBA has to refer back to the values of the spreadsheet anyway, back-and-forth?

General steer and advice would be appreciated. I know I have a large data set, but I'd like to be able to run this conversion code faster than 14 minutes.

Comment: You might do better on this question if you post it to the Code Review site - they deal with improving the performance of code whereas [so] is more for code that doesn't work

Comment: You could try it off an array instead `varArray=range("a1:x70000").value` and work off that.

Comment: Also look at `Range("P" & i)=switch(`

Comment: Not a speed improvement, but you're not making use of the `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONVERSION")... End With` block.  Each range within the block you're referencing is using, for example, `Range("M" & i)`. This will only operate on the currently active sheet.  You need to put a full-stop/period before the range for it to work on the Conversion sheet specifically:  `.Range("M" & i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use arrays - I've switched around you code and popped everything into an array to do the most of the work:

```
Sub SpeedUp()
Dim iLastRow As Long, iLastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim Arry() As Variant

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
iLastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'I'm assuming Row 1 is the header row. Also, if you're creating colums (to column Y) then just change this to "iLastCol = 25"

ReDim Arry(1 To iLastRow, 1 To iLastCol) ' This array is a 2 dimensionnel array and you can referance rows/columns within it like you would using Cells([Row number],[Column number])
Arry = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iLastRow, iLastCol))

For i = 6 To iLastRow
    If Arry(i, 13) = "BIN" Then '13 corresponds to column M
        Arry(i, 14) = "Duplicate"
    Else
        Arry(i, 14) = Arry(i, 2) & "-" & Arry(i, 4) & "-" & Arry(i, 13)
    End If

    If Arry(i, 2) = "Duplicate" Then
        Arry(i, 15) = "D"
        Else
        Arry(i, 15) = "N"
    End If

    If Arry(i, 5) = "Groundwater" Then
        Arry(i, 16) = "WG"
        ElseIf Arry(i, 5) = "Leachate" Then
        Arry(i, 16) = "LE"
        ElseIf Range("E2") = "Surface water" Then
        Arry(i, 16) = "WS"
        Else
        Arry(i, 16) = "Other"
    End If

'Plus another six If statements similar to the above to populate Cols P to Y... Not included here to keep this code on StackOverflow easier to read
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONVERSION").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iLastRow, iLastCol)) = Arry ' Sets all the values

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good, but I'm getting the message 'Compile error: Can't assign to array'...

Comment: @AndrewAbbott My bad - should work now.. let me know what times you get

Comment: I'm not quite there yet, now getting a Run-time error 13 Type mismatch... Might be worth adding that my header row is actually in Row 5.

Comment: FYI need to remove the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONVERSION")` part from Arry

Comment: @AndrewAbbott sorry you're right (never tested it!)  -  I've tweaked it again

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, all working now. A minor issue is that I'm losing my Tables but I can find a workaround for that. I've learned something too, so much appreciated.